# Can I route only the form section of my page - laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, forms, routes

I have a section on the home page of my site that contains a form called `@section('registration-form')`. I am unable to create a separate blade file like `register.blade.php` and then @yield it into the home page because the form yields after the page loads, messing up my javascript. Either way, I prefer to create a route that points directly to the form section of my page, not the entire page.

The purpose of doing this is to create a custom form, which needs a route from routes/web.php.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Is it possible to create a `Route::get()` that grabs the form `@section('registration-form')` only?

THE CODE:

home.blade.php

```
<!--- content from the home page exists here --->

<!--- form ---->

@section('registration-form')

<div class="col-lg-12">
 <form  method="POST" action="{{ `Syntax for GET request?` }}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}

 <div class="form-group" id="fname">
  <label for="name">First Name:</label>
  <input name="fname">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="email">
  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" required>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="password">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required>
 </div>
 <!---- more form questions ---->

@stop 
<!--- more content from home page exists here --->
```

Routes/web.php

```
Route::get( `HOW DO I POINT TO @section('registration-form')??` )
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after, but you can `@include()` other templates/views inside blade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: I added more details to better explain what I'm doing. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put this in your routes file to return the specific Blade view:

```php
Route::get('/whatever-you-want', function () {
    return view('registration-form', ['data' => 'data']);
});
```

Comment: The javascript needs to load before @section('registration-form') so it doesn't work. I also need to create a controller for this. I made a new question that you may be able to answer: [How To Load Javascript Before @Section - Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776781/laravel-5-4-how-to-make-javascript-load-before-section-yields). Thanks for your input